# Having Trouble Data Passing between WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, so I have a Form set up to load an additional form from a .dll, for added security, I want that .dll to read the state of a bool in the initial Form, essentially;

MainForm launches SecondForm (which is in a .dll)

SecondForm reads the state of the bool from MainForm and acts accordingly.

I thought I could use something like this
((Snipped from "SecondForm"))

```
Assembly asssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"MainForm.exe");
Type t = asssembly.GetType("MainForm.Form1");
object O = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
Form F = O as Form;
```

But that's as far as I get. I don't know how to reference the bool from "MainForm" on the "SecondForm"

Comment: Why don't you pass the bool to the second form instance when the MinForm creates the second form instance?

Comment: There is no need to use reflection for this.  Because mainform is launching SecondForm, just pass the value.

Answer (score 6):

Throw out all of that reflection stuff and just pass the value of the boolean from `MainForm` to `SecondForm` in `SecondForm`'s constructor. What you're doing in the sample code is creating an **entirely new** instance of `MainForm`, which is not what you want to do and makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to access any other property from MainForm you can implement constructor for SecondForm like this:

```
public SecondForm(Form theMainForm)
{
    var booleanValue = theMainForm.Value;
}
```